# Calling fragment within a fragment

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I have a custom fragment class which extends another fragment class. secondFragment class holds the views,layouts which I want to display in my tabFragment.

```
public class SecondFragment extends PrimaryFragment {

    public SecondFragment() {

    }

}
```

And, I have another Fragment class like this

```
 public class tabFragment extends Fragment {
   }
```

I'm adding the tabFragment to my Adapter to display it as my second tab.
Is it possible to call secondFragment inside my tabFragment?

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments regarding nested fragments

Comment: Using nested fragments, Bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is very much possible.

This link should answer your question - I think this should answer your question - [How to add tab inside fragment in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988654/how-to-add-tab-inside-fragment-in-android).

```
Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Frag Tab1"),
    NewsFragment.class, arg1);

Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Frag Tab2"),
    MyNestedFragment2.class, arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a tab navigation you shouldn't use nested fragments. You should use a ViewPager and Fragments. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging).

For working with nested Fragments you will have to use

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```